# Getting gradle error "Could not get unknown property 'srcDirs' for source set 'groovy'" after upgrading to 5.5.1

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project build and I'm including the groovy plugin in the master `build.gradle` like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
}
```

However, one of my subprojects which has groovy sources is doing this:

```
sourceSets {
  main { 
    java.srcDirs = []
    groovy.srcDirs += ["src/main/java", "src/main/groovy"]
  }
}
```

And I get an error:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'srcDirs' for source set 'groovy' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.
```

I'm in the process of upgrading my build scripts to work under gradle v5.5.1 rather than v2.13.  This was working previously where I had this in the subproject build file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

But after upgrading to 5.5.1 from 2.13 it started giving me this:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':mysubproj'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyBasePlugin']
   > Cannot change attributes of configuration ':mysubproj:apiElements' after it has been resolved
```

Which is why I thought I should declare the plugin in the master build script.

Shouldn't my plugin reference in the master build script make the subproject aware of the groovy extensions?  If not, what's the correct way?  Thank you!

Comment: Would it be possible to get copies of the root buildscript, and sub buildscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Groovy plugin isn't being applied to the subproject, you will want to apply it appropriately.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
}
```

I know in the past the new plugin style didn't work for subprojects, that may have been resolved and if so - use it.

As for the exception, when you seem to be doing the above, I'd need the buildscripts to advise you :)

Comment: Thanks, that works... do you know why this doesn't work in subprojects?  Not all subprojects require the plugin.  For my purposes, I guess it doesn't really matter but it kind of nags me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to be honest, I've never had any issues applying the Groovy or Kotlin plugins to subprojects - its quite bizarre. Did you only try with the new plugins syntax at all, or both?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the syntax for both, neither worked in subprojects but worked in allprojects.  Ce la vie! ;)